# Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format

Tags: activemq-classic

In our application, the Active MQ failover url looks like this:

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:9125?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0,tcp://localhost:9126?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0)?randomize=true
```

The app tries to connect to one of the urls randomly but if that url is not the primary url, it waits for a timeout of 10 seconds and then tries to reconnect to the other URL. 
I'm not sure which param is causing this wait to happen. And i don't want this wait. If the URL is not the primary URL, I want the app to reconnect to the other URL immediately.

Can anyone help me with this? any param changes, hints, suggestions are welcome and appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying a combination of different params in the tcp url, what finally worked for me was: maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100.
As mentioned by Hassen above, the default value for maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay is 10s. and i was not overriding this.

final url:

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:9125?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100,tcp://localhost:9126?useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=100)?randomize=true
```

Thanks for the research and help.

Answer (score 3):

if you set `wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0` --> **Inactivity monitoring is disabled when set to a value <= 0.**

> **maxInactivityDuration** : Timeout, in milliseconds, after which the connection is closed by the
>   broker if no data has been received.

`maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay` : **The initial delay before starting inactivity checks. default = 10s.**

`wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=1000`  **means after 1s if no data has been received the broker will close the connection !!?? is it a good idea ?**

try with :

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:9125?useInactivityMonitor=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=1000& wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10&initialReconnectDelay=10&maxReconnectAttempts=0&timeout=1000,tcp://localhost:9126?useInactivityMonitor=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=1000& wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10&initialReconnectDelay=10&maxReconnectAttempts=0&timeout=1000)?randomize=true
```

> Notes
>
> Under the Failover transport send operations will, by default,
>   block indefinitely when the broker becomes unavailable. There are two
>   options available for handling this scenario. First, either set a
>   TransportListener directly on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory, so that
>   it is in place before any request that may require a network hop or
>   second, set the timeout option. The timeout option causes the current
>   send operation to fail after the specified timeout.
>
> Example:
>
> failover:(tcp://primary:61616)?timeout=3000

**you have disabled the InactivityMonitor by transport.useInactivityMonitor=false**

> A value of false disables the InactivityMonitor completely and
>   connections will never time out.

take a look at parameters descriptions here

http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-inactivitymonitor.html#ActiveMQInactivityMonitor-AdvancedInactivityMonitorConfiguration

http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html#FailoverTransportReference-TransportOptions

Comment: Thanks Hassen. i will try your recommendations and update this thread.